# Cannot find module 'classnames'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting the following error when I try and run grunt on a react project

$ grunt server
Running "browserify:dist" (browserify) task

> > Error: Cannot find module 'classnames' from 'd:\wamp\www\react1\app\assets\js
> >     \components'
> >     Warning: Error running grunt-browserify. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You should post your package.json file, and the code of which file is trying to pull class names. That said it sounds like you're simply missing a dependency.

`npm install classnames --save`

Will add it to your package.json file and install it in node_modules. Re-run your grunt server after installing or updating any npm packages.

Comment: That got it to build -- now I get "Uncaught TypeError: React.render is not a function" when I try and view the app?

Comment: what is module classnames -- feels so generic?

Comment: Not sure what your React.render error is, double check that you're using the right version of react for your code base and such. ClassNames is a utility package for building html class attribute. It's a nice way for handling classes based on state and boolean values. Can see the various examples in the package's readme: https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

Answer (score 7):

First, install it with `npm install classnames`.
In Windows, everything will be fine if you write

```
import classNames from 'classnames'
```

but in Linux, I got this error that `'classnames' is not defined`...
and the problem was the capital letter I wrote `'classNames'` instead of `'classnames'` for module import, so consider that it might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using pnpm, maybe you need `shamefully-hoist = true`

Comment: At first I thought you are doing something unhelpfully joking here... But that was only because of my own lack of knowledge it seems. Cheers. But you could improve your post by trying for [answer]. Or...

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."